# How would I translate cm (centimeter) into German?

Tags: abbreviation

How would I translate cm. (centimeter) and also in. (inches) into German?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Das cm ist eine internationale Einheit die weltweit so gebraucht und nicht übersetzt wird. Ausgeschrieben wird es Zentimeter.

Das in. ist keine internationale Einheit und wird in Deutschland nicht verwendet - Ausnahmen sind manche Einheiten in der EDV, die eine Zeitlang schlicht übernommen wurden, bis man sich besann, dass es rechtsverbindliche Regelungen gibt, wodurch sich die kuriose Situation entwickelt hat, dass man als Kunde durch die Gewohnheit weiß, was ein 17"-Bildschirm ist, oder eine 21"-Bildschirmdiagonale, obwohl man sonst im Alltag immer mit Zentimetern hantiert, mit den Zentimetereinheiten aber nichts anfangen kann.

Analog bei der 5¼-Zolldiskette bzw. 3,5"-Diskette, womit die Übersetzung auch schon gegeben ist: Zoll. Da gerade Zahlen in Zoll in Zentimetern ausgedrückt sehr viele Nachkommastellen bekommen will sich da auch keine Umrechnung etablieren. Früher waren im Rohr- und Abwasserwesen sowie bei Schrauben Zollmaße durchaus üblich.

Comment: Wobei irgendwann in den 90ern mal 8,89-cm-Disketten verkauft wurden, bis man sich darauf besann, dass diese Zoll-Angaben auch als Gattungsangaben anstatt als Maßangaben gesehen werden konnten und die Angabe in Zoll daher in Ordnung ist/war.